# Actionscript 2.0 Angry Sun from SMB3

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I'm making a mario flash game in actionscript 2.0 and I was wondering how I can add the Angry Sun in this game. The angry sun from smb moves zig zag like towards the player/mario and if the angry sun touches mario/player the player dies.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qYp0qpfIwPw

Video for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You question is a bit vague and has many components.

You need a movieClip on the stage to represent the sun. I assume if you are programming a game you know how to do this but in case you are trying to do it dynamically from code read this for attachmovie

http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/42/1/Using-attachMovie/Page1.html

To change position of a movieclip in code

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000240.html

This article talks about performing an action using onEnterFrame

```
this.onEnterFrame = function() {
    my_mc._x = getProperty(_root, _xmouse);
};
```

so modify this code and change things so that it moves the sun relative to Mario based on your game logic.

To see if the sun touches, use hitTest
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001314.html

Make sure the Mario instance has an instance name which I assume it does as you likely are controlling it with code.